# Google Places API + Angular JS + PHP data not returning

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, google-places-api

Thanks for the help up front.  I am exploring building an app using data from the Google Places web services API.  I am using AngularJS, PHP and HTML.  As of now I am having an issue making the API results accessible to angular and subsequent HTMl page.  Any help would be much appreciated.

//HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans|Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
        <style>
        </style>
        <title>Test</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="myDiv" ng-controller="getPlaces">
            {{name}}
        </div>
        <script src="\myProject\angularJS.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

//Angular

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.config(['$qProvider', function ($qProvider) {
    $qProvider.errorOnUnhandledRejections(false);
}]);

myApp.controller('getPlaces', function($scope, $http) {
   $http.get("/myProject/getListofPlaces.php")
   .then(function(data){
       $scope.placesResults = data.data;
   });

});
```

//PHP

```
<?php

$handler = curl_init();
$header = array();
$header[] = 'Content-length: 0';
$header[] = 'Content-type: application/json';


    curl_setopt_array(
    $handler,
    array(
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER=> $header,
        CURLOPT_URL => 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&type=restaurant&keyword=cruise&key=MY_API_KEY',
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        )
    );

    $response = curl_exec($handler);
    curl_close($handler);
    $placesResults = json_decode($response, true);
    echo $placeResults;

?>
```

The results or the JSON looks something like this - I'd like to get the name of the place to display in my HTML.

```
{
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "results" : [
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : -33.86755700000001,
               "lng" : 151.201527
            },
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : -33.8662140697085,
                  "lng" : 151.2028105302915
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : -33.8689120302915,
                  "lng" : 151.2001125697085
               }
            }
         },
         "icon" : "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
         "id" : "ce4ffe228ab7ad49bb050defe68b3d28cc879c4a",
         "name" : "Sydney Showboats",
         "opening_hours" : {
            "open_now" : false,
            "weekday_text" : []
         },
         "photos" : [
            {
               "height" : 1152,
               "html_attributions" : [
                  "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/107415973755376511005/photos\"\u003eSydney Showboats\u003c/a\u003e"
               ],
               "photo_reference" : "CmRaAAAAXYq_pvvJuBivOnyfIFgtcidjSshkWpJ-nTC3anGmHSM2DaYiSsgrNXwCXlLfYPC01g8bDjitKqJ8oNPjIRcEp3WeDPBQDcL3wkrodbGZ7cViwV6O_JHB_A4uOr-AOWDkEhCwS0PplxpSuMcISfBISOpiGhQNiv2N8ljsWfU2iQ9mP-8J46HbRQ",
               "width" : 2048
            }
         ],
         "place_id" : "ChIJjRuIiTiuEmsRCHhYnrWiSok",
         "rating" : 3.8,
         "reference" : "CmRSAAAA6kANEdwze-e8q3GNEpbYX-Rp7Ukh18IXTUYviRP4JOW35rOULIi5rZWvdDrOJ9FaI0gcQW6Bf8YYVcoDbukWC1gXMcjldzi1FShcMJUK4Z_Wzc_SCJ-iTCZ7fVtvH4DxEhB6-HlZxiO3dBygcLUxCVVcGhQ8SRKBovx_rpWcCU7xEVVvn6l7UA",
         "scope" : "GOOGLE",
         "types" : [
            "travel_agency",
            "restaurant",
            "food",
            "point_of_interest",
            "establishment"
         ],
         "vicinity" : "32 The Promenade, Sydney"
      },
```

Comment: Try removing the Content-Length: 0 header in your php?

Comment: @alistaircol no, that didnt do anything :/

Comment: I am not sure what could be wrong, if your myProject/getListofPlaces.php is in your webroot. Add a second ``function (data)`` to your ``$http.get`` promise and ``console.log(data)`` you can see error angular gives when trying to load the page.

Comment: @alistaircol console log doesn't return anything.  Does that mean there is no error or it is not returning any data?  I am a noob at angular

Comment: @alistaircol I take that back.  I see the response now and everything looks OK to me.  {data: {…}, status: 200, headers: ƒ, config: {…}, statusText: "OK"}.  Do you think I am calling it wrong in my angular or referencing incorrectly in my HTML?

Comment: @alistaircol I solved it (below).  Thanks for your help.  The console log came in handy!

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer after a bit of help from @alistaircol
I basically needed point my scope go down a level in the placeResults object and then i needed to add reference to the placeResults in my HTML

//updated Angular

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.config(['$qProvider', function ($qProvider) {
    $qProvider.errorOnUnhandledRejections(false);
}]);

myApp.controller('getPlaces', function($scope, $http) {
   $http.get("/myProject/getListofPlaces.php")
   .then(function(data){
       //Edit #1
       $scope.placesResults = data.data.results;
   });

});
```

//updated HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans|Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
        <style>
        </style>
        <title>Test</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="myDiv" ng-controller="getPlaces">
             //Edit #2
            {{placesResults[0].name}}
        </div>
        <script src="\myProject\angularJS.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```